# Cómo activar/desactivar buttons del JFrame mediante java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una **aplicación** que quiero que **al arrancar compruebe si está activado el `MySQL`** en `Xampp`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que al ejecutar el `.jar` (escritorio) o el `.java` (Netbeans), compruebe si hay conexión a la base de datos y, si no la hay, desactive los botones. (`button_1`, `button_2`, `button_3`, `button_salir`).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se puede hacer a tiempo real, es decir, que cuando active en el XAMPP el MySQL automáticamente se activen los botones para poder acceder al programa? ¿O sería mejor tener un botón para volver a intentar conectar a la bbdd por mysql?

**Código Conexiones.java:**

```
public class Conexiones {
    static String bbdd = "agenda";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password = "root";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static Connection c = null;

    /**
     * Conexión a BBDD.
     *
     * @param bbdd
     * @return
     */
    public static Connection conexion_a_BBDD(String bbdd) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bbdd, login, password);
            return c;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException n){
            n.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Código Index.java:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * Interfaz para gestionar los clientes.
 */
public class Index extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Index() {
        initComponents();

        URL url_insertar = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/insertar.png");
        ImageIcon ico_insertar = new ImageIcon(url_insertar);

        URL url_modificar = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/modificar.png");
        ImageIcon ico_modificar = new ImageIcon(url_modificar);

        URL url_eliminar = this.getClass().getResource("/imagenes/eliminar.png");
        ImageIcon ico_eliminar = new ImageIcon(url_eliminar);

        //Situamos el JDialog en el centro de la pantalla.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //No redimensionable.
        setResizable(false);
    }


    private void button_salirMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        button_salir.setBackground(Color.decode("0xB4FF48"));
    }                                         

    private void button_salirMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        button_salir.setBackground(Color.white);
    }                                        

    private void button_salirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        int confirmado = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Deseas salir de la aplicación?", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == confirmado){
            this.dispose();
        }
    }                                            

    private void button_insertarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        Nuevo_cliente nc = new Nuevo_cliente(this, true);
        nc.setVisible(true);
    }                                               

    private void button_modificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        Modificar_cliente mc = new Modificar_cliente(this, true);
        mc.setVisible(true);
    }                                                

    private void button_eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        Eliminar_cliente ec = new Eliminar_cliente(this, true);
        ec.setVisible(true);
    }                                               

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton button_eliminar;
    private javax.swing.JButton button_insertar;
    private javax.swing.JButton button_modificar;
    private javax.swing.JButton button_salir;
    private javax.swing.JLabel label_anadir;
    private javax.swing.JLabel label_eliminar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel label_modificar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel label_titulo;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Podrías tener un hilo revisando cada cierto tiempo si la BD está disponible (intentando conectarse al puerto de MySQL, etc). Podrías hacerlo con un botón, también.

Comment: @Alfabravo No he visto hilos... ¿Alguna solución sencilla a mi cuestión?

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser posible comprobando la conexión a través del puerto que use el servidor de MySQL apuntando con un `Socket`:

```
private void verifyConnection(String url,int port) {
  try {
    Socket s=new Socket(url,port);
    enableMyButtons(true);
    s.close();
  } catch(IOException e) {
    enableMyButtons(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Tengo la función conexion_a_BBDD() la cual comprueba la conexion a MySQL, no? Y... ¿cómo la implemento en Index.java (el cual es el archivo ppal para activar/desactivar buttons? Cómo se podría implementar en mi código adjuntado

Comment: Siendo de ese modo... supongo que en algúna parte de `Index` quedaria una condición `if(miConexion.conexion_a_BBDD()!=null)`; si recuperas `true` los botones se habilitan, si `false` pues deshabilitados. como necesitas que arranque comprobando, puedes ubicar tal condicion dentro de un evento `WindowListener` o `WindowAdapter` usando el metodo `windowOpened`, no?

Comment: Lo he conseguido para comprobarlo al arrancar, pero si esta empieza deshabilitado, ¿cómo puedo comprobarlo para que automáticamente se habiliten los botones cuando se active el MySQL?